# Unicode characters in scanned Barcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, avfoundation

I have created one bar code scanner application and used AVFoundation native framework. Some of our barcode contains hidden unicode characters and we are unable to scan it. Here is an example of bar code:
]d201000000000010!0000-023
I am getting above code like: \u{1D}01000000000010\u{1D}0000-023

In above barcode ]d2 varies. I am unable to find type of the barcode. How can I parse that Unicode contained string into normal string? Does any one face this type of issue or barcode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`\u{1D}01000000000010\u{1D}0000-023` Looks to be a GS1-formatted barcode. Full spec is [here](https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf) And the values after the `{1D}` delimiter are call "application identifiers" and identify the type of data contained in that field. GS1 is really common in any industry where full supply-chain tracking is needed such as the medical device industry, etc. A concise list of application identifiers is [here](https://www.gs1-128.info/application-identifiers/)